# Why am I being warned about being blocked from asking questions?

Tags: support

I just went to post a new question, and at the top of the form I see a message saying:

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and
>   you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.
>
> For help formulating a clear, useful question, see: How do I ask a
>   good question?
>
> Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity.

I checked my user page, and I see there that I've asked 7 questions in total, with scores, in decreasing order, of 5, 5, 2, 2, 1, 1, and -1.

Does this really justify being warned about being blocked from asking questions? It seems the warning is disproportionate to the actual situation (a single question with 1 downvote).

Comment: It's a warning reminding you that you have some not so well received questions. Also you have  2 deleted questions

Comment: The two deleted questions were also closed.

Comment: @Sathya: What are my deleted questions?

Comment: @HighCommander4 these are your deleted questions: http://superuser.com/questions/428220/can-i-reply-to-a-message-on-a-mailing-list-that-i-am-not-subscribed-to and http://superuser.com/questions/141838/not-having-address-phone-number-in-whois-database

Comment: @nhinkle: thanks