# "questions have not been well-received" warning without negative or deleted questions

Tags: support, post-ban, bad-questions

I get the warning *"Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more."* I am struggling to find any cause for this; I cannot find any question that has been received badly.

[image]

I have a total of [8 questions](https://superuser.com/users/61723/hugorune?tab=questions) with an average question score of 2.25; only a single question has score 0 and **no question has a negative score**. The last question was more than three months ago.

I do not have any *[recently deleted questions](https://superuser.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/61723)*. <s>As far as I can tell I do not have any deleted questions at all.</s> I do actually have two deleted questions from 2012. One was put to sleep by the community user in february 2013 after a year with low views and a score of zero. [The other was migrated to stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317568/capturing-right-clickleft-click-with-autohotkey-unexpected-behaviour) and has a score of 2. I have not deleted any questions or answers myself.

I do have two questions that were closed as duplicates, but even so they have a positive score, so at least they were helpful to someone as a signpost. I also am not sure how I could improve duplicates by editing, and I really would like to take care of this warning before I ask more questions.

If I read my reputation history correctly, I have only ever received 2 downvotes, one of which was later undownvoted.

So I really cannot tell what triggered this warning and would appreciate some information here.

[None](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/8581/question-ban-warning-although-i-havent-yet-asked-anything) [of](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/8741/wait-some-of-your-past-questions-have-not-been-well-received-and-youre-in-dan) [the](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/8089/why-am-i-being-warned-about-being-blocked-from-asking-questions) [related](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/8206/is-the-ban-warning-too-strict) questions here on superuser seem to give any hint that is applicable for my situation. In all these cases there were at least some questions with a negative score involved.

What could have caused this warning; is this a bug or is there really something fundamentally wrong with my questions? Is there a minimum average score greater than 2.25 I need to aim for?

I have no intentions of asking more questions if they are not well received; ban or not, that just basic ettiquette. But I am struggling to figure out where I went wrong.

Comment: How many questions have been deleted by you or the community since you joined

Comment: When a question is deleted your reputation is returned, but the score is still tracked, if your getting this warning its valid.

Comment: I took a look, and well, there's two deleted questions but the most recent was deleted in 2013. Smells like a possible bug to me.

Comment: Thanks for the update about the deleted questions and the links, I have included the information in my meta question. Both deleted questions where from 2012, one deleted by community with score zero, the other successfully migrated to stackoverflow